# Windows 7 can't connect to Snow Leopard via Bluetooth PAN internet sharing?

Tags: network, snow-leopard, windows, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect Windows 7 to Snow Leopard via Bluetooth PAN but it doesn't seem to detect the Bluetooth PAN capability of the mac. It only allows transferring of files, and using it as a bluetooth speaker.

I've already done the following:

- System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced > Share my internet connection with other Bluetooth devices
- System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing On > Bluetooth PAN
- System Preferences > Sharing > Bluetooth Sharing